# Other objects than strings in ExposedDropdownMenu

Tags: android, kotlin, material-design

I want to use the `AutoCompleteTextView` (together with the `TextInputLayout`) as specified in the MaterialDesign documentation as an Exposed Dropdown Menu. Is it possible to use custom objects with it? So I could retrieve the selected object with something like `getSelectedItem`?

MD docs: https://material.io/components/menus/android#exposed-dropdown-menus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to use custom objects with it?

Yes you can.

Suppose you were creating User's exposed Dropdown menu:

```
data class User(val id: String, val name: String) {

    override fun toString(): String {
        return name
    }
}
```

Create list item layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceSubtitle1" />
```

Create your Adapter:

```
val adapter = ArrayAdapter<User>(context, R.layout.list_item_user, emptyList())

autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter)
autoCompleteTextView.setOnItemClickListener { _, _, position, _ ->
    val selectedTeam: User? = arrayAdapter.getItem(position)
}
```

That's It. Happy Coding! :)